Rapoport and Zink's notion of decent isocrystal
All the notions and definitions I'm going to recall come from Rapoport and Zink's book "Period spaces for $p$-divisible groups" (1996). Let us fix $p$ a prime number. First, some notations.

$G$ a linear algebraic group over $\mathbb Q_p$.
$L$ a perfect field of characteristic $p$.
$W(L)$ the ring of Witt vectors of $L$.
$K_0 := W(L)_{\mathbb Q}$ the unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ whose residue field is $L$.
$\sigma$ the Frobenius morphism $x\mapsto x^p$ on $L$. It can be lift to an automorphism on $W(L)$ and on $K_0$ which is still denoted by $\sigma$.
$\mathbf D$ the algebraic torus over $\mathbb Q_p$ whose character group is $\mathbb Q$.

Rapoport and Zink define two compatible notions of decency. One for $\sigma$-conjugacy classes in the group $G(K_0)$, the other for isocrystals over $L$. While the second definition is easy to formulate, the first is a little bit more convoluted (and more general). Let me recall both of them.
Decency for $\sigma$-conjugacy classes.
In his paper "Isocrystals with additional structures" (1985), Kottwitz associates, to any element $b\in G(K_0)$, a map $\nu_b: \mathbf D \to G_{K_0}$ which is called the slope morphism in Rapoport and Zink's book. This name is justified since $\nu_b$ is, in some sense, universal for slope decomposition of isocrystals associated to $b$ and to $\mathbb Q_p$-rational representations of $G$. I won't make this statement more precise here.
A $\sigma$-conjugacy class $\overline{b} \subset G(K_0)$ is decent if there exists some $b\in \overline{b}$ such that $(b\sigma)^s = s\nu_b(p)\sigma^s$ in $G(K_0) \rtimes \langle \sigma \rangle$ for some integer $s>0$.
This definition is relatively obscure to me, since $\nu_b$ is itself difficult to grasp in my opinion, even after going through Kottwitz' original construction.
Definition for isocrystals over $L$.
An isocrystal over $L$ is a finite dimensional $K_0$-vector space $N$ together with a $\sigma$-linear automorphism $\Phi$. An isocrystal $(N,\Phi)$ is called decent if the $K_0$-vector space $L$ is generated by vectors $n\in N$ satisfying an equation of the form $\Phi^s n = p^r n$ for some integers $r$ and $s>0$.
NB: the formulation from the book is a little bit ambiguous. Should we read it as $r \in \mathbb Z$ and $s>0$, or $r,s>0$? Also, note that $r$ and $s$ are allowed to depend on $n$. If the isocrystal is isoclinic of slope $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$, then one can choose a single pair $(r,s)$ independent on $n$ and we have $\frac{r}{s} = \lambda$.
The question.
The compatibility between the two notions is as follows. Let $(N,\Phi)$ be an isocrystal over $L$ and let $V \subset N$ be a $\mathbb Q_p$-vector space inside $N$, containing a basis for $N$. Thus, we have an isomorphism $N \simeq V \otimes_{\mathbb Q_p} K_0$. Let $G = \mathrm{GL}(V)$ as an algebraic group over $\mathbb Q_p$. One can write $\Phi = b(\mathrm{id}_V \otimes \sigma)$ for some $b\in G(K_0)$. Then $(V,\Phi)$ is decent if and only if $\overline{b}$ is decent.

Assume that $(N,\Phi)$ is an isoclinic isocrystal over $L$. Assume that $(N,\Phi)$ is decent and choose some $V \subset N$ and $b\in \mathrm{GL}(V)(K_0)$ as above. Let $s_1 > 0$ be the smallest integer such that $b$ satisfies a decency equation with $s=s_1$ as in the first definition. Let $s_2>0$ be the smallest integer $s$ such that $N$ is generated by vectors $n$ such that $F^s n = p^r n$ for some $r$. Do we have $s_1 = s_2$?

An example.
Let $\mathcal E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ whose Frobenius satisfy the equation $\mathcal F^2 + p = 0$. Let $N = M(E[p^{\infty}])_{\mathbb Q}$ be the isocrystal of the Dieudonné module of the $p$-divisible group of $E[p^{\infty}]$. Then $N$ is a $\mathbb Q_p$-vector space of dimension $2$ and $\Phi$ is induced by the Frobenius $\mathcal F$. In particular we have $\Phi^2 = -p$ on $N$. Thus, we have $\Phi^4 = p^2$ so that $(N,\Phi)$ is decent and $s_2 = 4$.
On the other hand, in a suitable basis $\Phi$ is given by the matrix $b := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -p \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}(N)$. What would $s_1$ be in this case? Or in other words, how can I write down $\nu_b$ explicitely?
Motivation (kind of).
Rapport and Zink define a Weil descent datum for their moduli spaces of (EL) or (PEL) type. However the datum is only defined over a field $L$ which contains $\mathbb F_{p^s}$ where $s$ is the (smallest) integer involved in the decency equation for the $\overline b$ determined by the underlying algebraic datum. For instance, in my example above, if my question were true then the Rapoport-Zink space attached to $\mathcal E[p^{\infty}]$ could only be descended to $W(\mathbb F_{p^4})$, even though my elliptic curve is really defined over $\mathbb F_p$, which feels kind of off. I would expect that it descends at least to $W(\mathbb F_{p^2})$ (in order to have all endomorphisms defined). That's why I need a reality check on what this integer $s$ really is, and how to think about Rapoport-Zink's requirements on $L$.

I look forward to reading this question with greater care and try to find a solution, but I wanted to say already that it might be a better fit for MO.

@Aphelli Yeah, I have hesitated to post this on MO, but I reconsidered because this isn't really a meaningful question, rather just a matter of definitions. From experience, there are people (like you!) on Mathstack who know this kind of stuff pretty well too.

I’m trying to parse your question for now and I don’t understand the domain or range of $\nu_b$. In the first definition of decent, shouldn’t it be $\nu_b(p)^s$ instead of $s\nu_b(p)$?

@Aphelli Yeah, you must be right. The notation $s\nu_b$ used in the book should mean "$\nu_b$ to the power $s$".

How is $p$ an element of $\mathbf{D}$ or of $\mathbf{D}(K_0)$?

@Aphelli The source really seems to be $\mathbf D$, though the authors mention that $s\nu_b$ factors through a morphism $\mathbb G_m \to G$ for suitable integers $s$. I'll be honest, this too is somewhat obscure to me

Are you sure that there’s no nice definition of $\nu_b$ when $G$ is some $GL(V)$, where $V$ is a $K_0$-vector space coming from an isocrystal?

@Aphelli I guess that this is the point, precisely. No matter the reference I look at, I can only find definitions/constructions of this slope morphism, but no example to work it out.

@Aphelli Example 1.10 of this paper specializes to the case of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$. Restricting to an isoclinic component $V_{\lambda}$ of $(V\otimes K_0,\Phi := b(\mathrm{id}\otimes \sigma))$ of slope $\lambda$, the map $\nu_b$ is given by $\lambda \cdot \mathrm{id}{V{\lambda}}$, ie. the composition $\mathbf D \xrightarrow{\lambda} \mathbb G_m \subset \mathrm{GL}(V_{\lambda})$. Yet, I'm still not at ease with this. What are the integers $s$ such that it makes sense to evaluate $s\lambda \cdot \mathrm{id}{V{\lambda}}$ at $p$?  http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1996__103_2_153_0.pdf

I thought you had to evaluate $\nu_b$ at $p$ first, ie $p$ has to live in $\mathbf{D}(K_0)$? Unless I’m mistaken, $\mathbb{D}$ is the inverse limit of a system of copies $A_n$ of $\mathbb{G}m$ with the map $A_n \rightarrow A{n-1}$ being the $n$-th power for $n \geq 2$.

@Aphelli I think you are right about the construction of $\mathbf D$. Then $s\nu_b(p)$ should read as $s\nu_b$ evaluated at $p$, this seems to agree with notations in other papers in the literature. The map $s\nu_b$ seems to be the composition $\mathbf D \xrightarrow{s} \mathbf D \xrightarrow{\nu_b} G_{K_0}$ (this is defined for $s\in \mathbb Q^{\times}$, which acts on $\mathbf D$ since it acts on its character group). For suitable integers $s$, the map $s\nu_b$ factors through the projection $\mathbf D \to \mathbb G_m$ induced by the inclusion $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ of character groups

I am posting a partial answer in the case $b$ is basic. While I don't totally understand the notions, I found out that, given an integer $s$ such that $s\nu_b$ factors through $\mathbb G_m$ (cf. the comment section), then $s\nu_b$ acts like multiplication by $p^r$ on the isoclinic component $N_{r/s} \subset N$ of slope $\frac{r}{s}$. This is written explicitely in the paragraph 6.25 of Rapoport and Zink's book. For instance, in my example, $b$ is basic since the elliptic curve is supersingular, and $N$ is isoclinic of slope $\frac{1}{2}$. I suspect that $s\nu_b$ factors through $\mathbb G_m$ if and only if $s$ is even. Then $2\nu_b(p)$ should correspond to the matrix $p\mathrm{Id} \in \mathrm{GL}(N)$. In particular the decency equation for $b$ does not hold for $s=2$ as $b^2 = -p\mathrm{Id}$. Thus, $s_1 = 4 = s_2$.
